# Can't start tomcat ( org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: )

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, illegalaccessexception

I am trying to develop a web application program I'm using `tomcat 9` and `hibernate` .  my application was running correctly but suddenly i got this error :

```
18-May-2021 11:35:04.881 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
18-May-2021 11:35:04.882 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
18-May-2021 11:35:04.892 WARNING [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [ROOT] registered the JDBC driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.[2021-05-18 11:35:04,905] Artifact servlet-hibernate:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
18-May-2021 11:35:09.620 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1037)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and it could not deploy the artifact any more .
and in order to find out the reason of this error :

```
   18-May-2021 11:35:04.881 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
```

when I check the log file in tomcat I found these Errors :

```
18-May-2021 11:45:13.814 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8081]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1049)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:746)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:428)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:300)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:253)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1204)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1217)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1046)
    ... 13 more

18-May-2021 11:45:17.472 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await Failed to create server shutdown socket on address [localhost] and port [8005] (base port [8005] and offset [0])
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketBind(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:106)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.bind(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:382)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:190)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:375)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:864)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:810)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:342)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:473)
```

by the way I can not find tomcat process  with this command  `get-process|select-string "tomcat"` in windows PowerShell. so I think the main problem is with starting the tomcat .
also you should know when I run this command :
`c:\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.46-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.46\bin>startup.bat` in a CMD the following windows will appear .
[image: tomcat startup.bat]

and nothing will change , as long as I wait .
Conclusion :
I think my tomcat is not started yet . and also I wonder  if I restarted the tomcat eventually  would it be helpful to solve this Error :

```
18-May-2021 11:35:09.620 INFO [Abandoned connection cleanup thread]   org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading Illegal access: this web   application instance has been stopped already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown  for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped  already. Could not load []. The following stack trace is thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access.
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkStateForResourceLoading(WebappClassLoaderBase.java :1384)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1037)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.checkContextClassLoaders(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:96)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.run(AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.java:69)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really get confused . I appreciate any solution .

Comment: If you run Tomcat through `startup.sh`, the name of the executable is `java.exe`, not `tomcat`. That should help you find the process, which already uses the configured port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to restart your server then restart IDE and rebuild project also may help. On the other hand you probably can find a process with your port using cmd and the following command `netstat -ano | findstr "yourPortNumber"`

But I truly recommend you to check your configured port firstly using `server.xml` file in your Tomcat directory and after that resolve your bind conflict.